# Linux RDP/VNC/SSH Client

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc

I use loads of machines daily.  Each uses different connection methods, either remote desktop, VNC or SSH.  My desktop is Linux, it would be nice if I had a tabbed interface for them all so I don't have to remember which is VNC, which is RDP etc.

Does anyone know of any of the following:

- A tabbed VNC, remote desktop and SSH client OR
- A tabbed VNC AND remote desktop client OR
- A tabbed VNC client OR
- A tabbed remote desktop client

Bullet points are in priority order, I'd prefer have a client that supports them all to prevent my taskbar becoming cluttered.  It's important that I'm able to detach tabs however, so I can move specific tabs to another monitor.

Comment: What descktop environment do you use (or have available)? KDE/Gnome/etc.?

Comment: I use Gnome, although have all the KDE libs so could use an application for either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Grdc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grdc/) looks like one option, though I don't have any experience with it myself.

It supports RDP (Remote Desktop), VNC, and SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, there is the KDE application Krdc but I believe it only supports VNC and RDP, not SSH.  (And actually to be honest, sometimes it hasn't worked for me... not sure what's up with that)